# installing dada2 into a version of R that was installed through condas

Tags: r, installation, conda

I have an environment with R installed through condas (I currently use R with jupyter notebook, so this made sense at one point). I would like to use dada2 with this version of R.

As per this site https://anaconda.org/bioconda/bioconductor-dada2 the correct command to make this happen is

```
 conda install -c bioconda bioconductor-dada2
```

which gives me the following error

Fetching package metadata .............
Solving package specifications: .

> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in
>   conflict:
>     - bioconductor-dada2 -> bioconductor-biostrings >=2.32.1 -> bioconductor-biocgenerics >=0.15.6 -> r 3.3.1* -> r-base 3.3.1
>     - r-glue Use "conda info " to see the dependencies for each package.

If I run `conda info package r-glue` I can see that it depends on r-base 3.4.1.

*Alternative approach that also doesn't work:*

I also tried going into R and installing from there, but I can't get any packages to install with R packages

```
 source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
 biocLite("dada2")
```

Gives me a really long output, but the short of it is that a bunch of the dependencies return errors

> ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RcppParallel’
>   * removing ‘/home/jacob/anaconda3/lib/R/library/RcppParallel’ ERROR: dependency ‘S4Vectors’ is not available for package ‘IRanges’
>   * removing ‘/home/jacob/anaconda3/lib/R/library/IRanges’ ERROR: dependencies ‘S4Vectors’, ‘IRanges’, ‘matrixStats’ are not available
>   for package ‘DelayedArray’

and then more stuff and at the end

ERROR: dependencies ‘Biostrings’, ‘ShortRead’, ‘RcppParallel’ are not available for package ‘dada2’
* removing ‘/home/jacob/anaconda3/lib/R/library/dada2’

> The downloaded source packages are in
>     ‘/tmp/Rtmptx8OqE/downloaded_packages’ Updating HTML index of packages
>   in '.Library' Making 'packages.html' ... done Old packages: 'curl',
>   'dplyr', 'foreign', 'haven', 'httpuv', 'mgcv', 'purrr',   'Rcpp',
>   'TTR', 'xts' Update all/some/none? [a/s/n]:

and then all of the updates fail too.

Is the correct answer to not try to use dada2 with condas in R and rather just use a condas independent version of R, or is there some way that I am missing?

I am running R version 3.4.1 on ubuntu linux 16.04 and conda 3.2.23 for what that is worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also struggled with this issue. After engaging in some discussions contained in github issues, I learned that the order of your channels actually needs to be different from what the `bioconductor` channel documentation suggests. Making this be my `.condarc` for the environment where I'm installing dada2 fixed the problem.

.condarc

```
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - defaults
```

In case it helps anyone, you can look here: https://github.com/abalter/dada2-tools

Comment: Neat! Which version of R were you using when you got this to work? 3.3.1 or something newer?

Comment: So, I've spent a lot of time on this, and it's pretty gnarly. DADA2 will currently install with R v3.5.1. However, when I create the environment there are problems, especially if I try to run it in RStudio Server or a Jupyter notebook. The only way I found to fix it was to downgrade `krb5` after installing. This bumps R back to 3.4.1. In any case, I created a script I use to create my dada2 envrinment: https://github.com/abalter/dada2-tools/blob/master/create-dada2_conda_env.

Comment: Running with miniconda on lubuntu 18.10 64 bit worked for me. One hang up I had for a while many packages are only available for 64 bit linux, and for whatever reason, the first time I tried to use it was on a 32 bit system. Such a configuration results in nothing good.

Answer (score 0):

I found downgrading my R version to 3.3.1 seemed to fix the problem.
To do that I first removed R

```
 conda remove r
```

Checked to make sure that worked with `conda list`

Then I re-installed an older version of r
     conda install r==3.3.1

followed by dada2

```
 conda install -c bioconda bioconductor-dada2
```

which worked. and finally I added r-essentials (which I needed especially to get jupyter notebook to work)

```
 conda install -c bioconda bioconductor-dada2
```

With that, everything seems to work as expected.